# How can I crop away a tensor’s constant value padding (padding height and width are the same) with an unknown value and size?

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, padding, crop

How can I crop away a tensor’s constant value padding (padding height and width are the same) with an unknown value and size?

I would think that because the padding surrounding my tensor has a constant value, and the same height / width, that it should be possible to know where to crop the tensor to remove the padding.

```
import torch

# Test tensor with NCHW dimensions
a = torch.randn(1,4,5,5) # Can have any H & W size

# Create padding for testing
b = torch.nn.functional.pad(a, (2,2,2,2), 'constant', value=1.2) # Value can be any number

c = # equal to a, without being able to use the variables a or b (or their argument values)
```

NumPy solutions are acceptable as I can easily convert them to PyTorch.

Edit:

```
pad = torch.where(b[0, 0] - b[0, 0, 0, 0] != 0)[0][0]

x_pad, y_pad = 0, 0
if (b.size(3) % 2) == 0:
    x_pad = 1
if (b.size(2) % 2) == 0:
    y_pad = 1
c = b[:, :, pad : -(pad + y_pad), pad : -(pad + x_pad)]

assert c == a
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get an idea of the content of a feature map by taking its middle row and measure the padding by looking for the first element change:

```
midrow = b[0, 0, b.shape[3]//2, :]
pad = (midrow[:-1] == midrow[:1])[:midrow.shape[0]//2].sum()
```

Alternatively you could substract one of the feature maps with the padding value and find the first non zero value, which would be the padding size:

```
pad = torch.where(b[0,0] - b[0,0,0,0] != 0)[0][0]
```

Having the padding, we can discard the right amount of values around the feature maps for all batch elements and all channels:

```
a = b[:, :, pad:-pad, pad:-pad]
```

Comment: Thank you! Solution number 2 seems to work the best for me, but I had to add an offset for cases when the original unpadded tensor has odd dimensions.

Comment: For example: when using `a` with shape `1, 3, 5, 5`, solution 2: `pad = torch.where(b[0,0] - b[0,0,0,0] != 0)[0][0]; b[:, :, pad:-pad, pad:-pad]` returns back `a`, not for you?

Comment: Yeah, it's not quite `a` as it can leave an extra line on the right hand side and the bottom side. I added an edit with the edits I made.

Comment: For example, when I tested an input size of torch.Size([1,3, 28, 28]), that contained a square of torch.Size([1,3,5,5]), there would be an extra line of constant values on the bottom and right side.

Comment: Oh I see, I didn't know you had this edge case. I though padding was equally applied to both sides.

Comment: No worries, I'm using it to crop the output from neural networks, and sometimes the output is not completely centered. I didn't realize this was the case until I tested it.